# Managing video stream buffering in Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, buffering, android-videoview

I have an issue with streaming video file via HTTP. VideoView is used.

And I have noticed that buffer percentage decrease when seeking back. Also I have noticed that video start downloading once again if it is replaying.

Is it possible to provide some kind of cache for video buffer. And how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can download/stream large file into small chunk of files. Play these chunk files one by one. In this case you should make proper use of MediaPlayer. - thanks

Comment: Yes, it is a solution. But what is the proper way to split video? Do you know any source example?

Comment: You have HTTP based comm. which connects to video data source & downloads/streams bytes of data to your device , here while receiving data bytes you can create chunks several of say 1Mbs. Did u understand this?

Comment: I have tried to download chunks of stream but when VideoView can't play partial file.

Comment: Lets say u have 10Mb video. Once first you have let say 2Mbs of data, you write that file to SDCard and init video player to play #FILE1 , now mean while you start storing data to FILE#2 , once player is done with FILE#1 load file #2 and start storing data to #File3 .. write back ..

Comment: I have understood your idea. But VideoView throws "Cannot play video" while attempting to play #FILE1

Comment: Please post error log & Pseudo code of implementation..this will help me to understand it..I have developed OnlineStreaming app named gDocsLiveStreaming http://goo.gl/V0o9G..

Comment: @darja Not all video formats are encoded to be streamed, or are suitable for streaming.